# Get average time a pod stays in a pending state

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to calculate the average time a pod stays in a pending state in grafana with prometheus. I can generate a graph to get the number of pods in a pending state over time, with this query

```
sum(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"})
```

However, I would really like to get an the value of the average time that the pods are staying in this state in the last X hours. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The metric `kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"}` will only give you binary values i.e., 0/1.
1 if the pod is in pending state, 0 otherwise.
Also, the data is being updated every 30s.
So to find the total time it was in pending in last X hours, you can do something like.

```
sum_over_time(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"}[Xh]) * X * 30
```

For better visualization, you can use table in grafana.

Answer (score 5):

PromQL provides [aggregation functions over time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time).

You specify the [range of time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors) in the expression ; for X previous hours, it will be:

```
avg_over_time(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"}[Xh])
```