# Finding the duration of Kubernetes Pods in Datadog?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, datadog

I am trying to aggregate the pod duration of the status **Running** over another custom business-logic tag. Then I can calculate how much it cost me to run this service.

I have tried to use `docker.uptime` but it has not been fruitful as I imagine multiple containers can be run in parallel per node. I saw that Datadog KSM provides `pods.age` and `pods.uptime` metrics but they do not appear in Datadog metric explorer.

I do not want to use Prometheus/Grafana to do this because I think this should be possible with Datadog. [Prometheus Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517235/get-average-time-a-pod-stays-in-a-pending-state)

Answer (score 0):

`avg:container.uptime{kube_namespace:<your namespace>} by {pod_name}`